how to interact with other android apps from Qt
I'm working on a messenger with C++, Qt, QML. Now I got access to permission with AndroidMainfest.xml and i need to get phone contacts, looking ahead i will need to interact with the camera, microphone, etc.
I Googled how it can be done, but people everywhere say that this can only be done with AndroidJNI and Java.
But now apparently by the lack of documentation for a query like Qt 6.7 AndroidJnuiObject, it's impossible to do it like before. And now I don't understand how to do it. Well, I need to find other ways to interact with other android apps.
I have read the documentations: QCoreApplication, Application Permissions, QPermission. Now I'm trying to find other documentation that might be useful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

An example to use JNI android API https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html
